# Unpack requires a string argument of length 44 python

Tags: python, tcp, garbage-collection, ip, packet

I have while loop for get packets

```
unpackedData = struct.unpack("!BBHHHBBH4s4sHH4s4s4sHH4s", data[:44])
```

this line throws exception

> Unpack requires a string argument of length 44 python

But after using debugger i noticed that it happens after few loops, I think its because cache is filled.

Is there any way to clear python cache or destroy objects or something like that?

Comment: What else happens to `data` in the while loop?  Is it shortened?  Python will happily allow you to have indices way out of range (in a slice):  `'foo'[:500]` gives you just `'foo'`

Comment: Have you checked that `len(data) >= 44`?  Keep in mind that `len('abc'[:44]) == 3`.

Comment: @zigg -- those were my thoughts exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that in your while loop, you're shortening the `data` string each time by 44 characters, however, 44 doesn't divide your original string evenly so at the last iteration you're left with a piece of the string that is less than 44 characters long.

python doesn't complain about the slicing, it just returns a string which is smaller than you expect.  e.g.:

```
print len("foo"[:500])  #3
print "foo"[:500]       #foo
```